# Filter certain elements in Ember.ListView. JSfiddle inside

Tags: javascript, listview, ember.js

I am using `Ember.ListView` collection. I tried to simulate my problem through this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aQ4UB/ .
I would to show only the elements matching with a certain boolean condition. But i am filtering in handlebars. **As a consequence I got blank lines**.

Here a simple snippet. **Controller definition**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    var content = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if(i%2 == 0) // simulate a certain condition of visibility
            content.push({  name: "Item " + i, isVisible:true  });
        else
            content.push({  name: "Item " + i, isVisible:false  });
    }
    controller.set('content', content);
  }
});
```

**listView**

```
App.ListView = Ember.ListView.extend({
  height: 500,
  rowHeight: 50,
  width: 500,
  itemViewClass: Ember.ListItemView.extend({
                                                    // handlebar
     template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#if isVisible}}{{name}}{{/if}}'),
  })
});
```

**output**

```
Item 0

    <------------------- "Blank" element

Item 2

    <------------------- "Blank" element

Item 4
```

Complete code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQ4UB/)

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Maybe I have to call `rerender` function. In what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also take a look at [Ember filter property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterProperty) useful in common cases, and just `filter()`

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content:null,
    filteredItems : function(){
         var filteredItems = [] ;
        var items = this.get('content');
        if(items.length)
            for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                if(items[i].item % 2 == 0)
                    filteredItems.push(items[i]);
            }
       return filteredItems;
    }.property('content')
});

App.ListView = Ember.ListView.extend({
  height: 500,
  rowHeight: 50,
  width: 500,
  itemViewClass: Ember.ListItemView.extend({
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{item}}'),
  })
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
      var content = [{item : 1},{item : 2},{item : 3},{item : 4},{item : 5},{item : 6}];
      controller.set('content', content);
  }
});
```

---

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{collection App.ListView contentBinding="controller.filteredItems"}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should filter the array ahead of time using a computed property making use of the [`Ember.Array` `rejectProperty()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_rejectProperty).

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Route.extend({
    filteredContent: function() {
      return this.get('content').rejectProperty('isVisible', false);
    }.property('content.@each')
});
```

Now, if you access `filteredContent` it will be an array containing only the items that have `isVisible` set to `true`.  The handlebars would then be:

JS:

```
template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{name}}'),
```

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{collection App.ListView contentBinding="filteredContent"}}
</script>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQ4UB/1/)